# How can I use maizzle with laravel blade?

Tags: laravel

I've tried everything but I can't seem to figure out how I can have a local version of maizzle which uses urls from my laravel env app_url and for images if local I would need it to use images/logo.png but when built for production I need it to use the blade {{ asset() }} directive.

Basically want to be able to preview my maizzle like normal locally but when built for production have it all convert for blade.

Any ideas?

Already setup my config.js and config.production.js to place the built files into the correct laravel directories, only have an issue with trying to have a local AND production environment which uses URLs and variables depending on the environment